# Android tv box has been compromised

Tags: malware, spyware, rat

how can I get remote access to android box the the other people has to it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try a hardware factory reset of your Android TV. Since you have not detailed your model, I'm afraid you will have to find out how to do that yourself - it will probably be in the manual for your specific device.

Comment: thanks for answer. I just wanted to see what kind of access hackers have to my device ? what kind of information they are getting from android box. I meant, if could have hacked version access to that box. Its 95max android box with android 9.0

Comment: A hacker would be able to see any information that was present on your device.